# Bundling non-native npm modules with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

**Description**

I have a `nodejs + TypeScript + express` project and currently the source `*.ts` files are being bundled with `webpack` and `node_modules` is ignored with `webpack-node-externals`.

When I deploy `bundle.js` in Docker, I would need to still run `npm i --production` on the target image to install the dependencies, which installs all the modules listed in `package.json`

**The Problem:**

If I am using only *one function* from `lodash` which does not have native parts, the whole `lodash` module (4.8MB) is installed nonetheless (which is intended).

This results in a huge `node_modules` folder where functions inside packages aren't always necessarily used in `bundle.js`. This problem is especially prevalent when containerizing the application with Docker.

Is there any way to bundle non-native modules with Webpack while leaving native modules alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54393299/2234013 - I believe you're looking for `nodeExternals({ whitelist })` and `babel-loader` `exclude`:

```js
  // excerpt from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54393299/2234013
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      whitelist: [/lodash/] 
    })
  ],
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        ...
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(lodash).*/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          ...
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```